# Need Help Toggle Open & Close Function

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript code that is working just fine on toggling a div open/close. The part that I have not been able to get to work is that when the div is on a closed state I would like it to show a "Read More" and when it is open I would like it to show a "Read Less".

Here is the code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function () {
    $('#open-content').click(function () {
        $("#me").show({
            height: 'toggle'
        }, 1000);
    }), $("#clickme").click(function () {
        //do nothing if hovered over
    }, function () {
        //hide on hover out
        $("#me").hide({
            height: 'toggle'
        }, 1000);
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="open-content" class="button">Read More +</a>
<div id="me">
    <div class="divider clear"></div>
    <div class="inner-content scroll-pane">
    Content
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#me").slideToggle(0);
$('#open-content').click(function () {
    $(this).text($(this).text() == "Read More +" ? "Read Less -" : "Read More +")
    $("#me").slideToggle(1000);
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/EL3Bn/)**

Answer (score 0):

Change the text of the anchor **open-content** using below code during the click event,

```
$('#open-content').text("Read Less")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this within the onclick function.

```
$(this).text("Read Less");
```

or

```
$(this).html("Read Less");
```

Either should work.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check to see if the div is visible or not.

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $('#open-content').click(function() {
  $('.scroll-pane').toggle();
  if ($('.scroll-pane').is(":visible")){
    $('#open-content').text("Read Less -");
  }
  else{
    $('#open-content').text("Read More +");
  }

  });

});
```

HTML:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script><a href="#" id="open-content" class="button">Read Less -</a>

<div id="me">
<div class="divider clear"></div>
<div class="inner-content scroll-pane">
Content
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/AVaqIxU/1/